# XSL foreach attributes as HTML input attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Okay, I'm trying to be able to dynamically set the input attributes via an XML tag.  For example:

```
<text name='text_name' value='text_value'>text_display</text>
```

I want to run a foreach to make it so name, value, or any other attribute in `<text>` will be inserted as an attribute for the HTML input and use the value of the `<text>` as the label/placeholder.

```
<xsl:for-each select="text">
    <label><xsl:value-of select="." /></label>
    <input type='textfield' placeholder='{.}' />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now I know I can use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
```

but I don't know how to insert that into the input tag.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use [push focused (rather than pull-focused) XSLTs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xdpshpul.html) with more `apply-templates` and less `for-each` statements.

There is nothing that says the definition of an element or its attributes must be in the same template. So when you make the template for the `<text>` element, you can just create the `<input>` element and `apply-templates` over all of the attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="text">
 <input>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <label><xsl:value-of select="." /></label>
 </input>
</xsl:template>
```

Secondly, what you are trying to do is literally copy the attributes into the new document, so rather than recreate them, just `copy` them, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="text/@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

## So, here is a complete stylesheet...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/texts">
 <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
 <input>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <label><xsl:value-of select="." /></label>
 </input>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## ... when applied to this input XML document...

```
<texts>
  <text name='text_name' value='text_value'>text_display</text>
  <text name='text_name2' value='text_value2'>other_display</text>
</texts>
```

## ... gives this result XML

```
<input name="text_name" value="text_value">
    <label>text_display</label>
</input>
<input name="text_name2" value="text_value2">
    <label>other_display</label>
</input>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still new to XSLT so I appreciate the link and advice.